# Recaptcha with scala and play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, captcha, recaptcha

by using [tutorial](http://techminded.net/blog/adding-captcha-in-playframework2.html) , i am trying to apply captcha in my play project.

HTML

```
<form action="/applyForWork" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="relevant" id="relevant" >
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <br/>
        @Html(views.ReCaptcha.render())
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Controller

```
def applyForWork = Action {
    implicit request =>
      println(request.body.asFormUrlEncoded) //None
      Ok("submitted")
  }
```

> Q1.why this `println(request.body.asFormUrlEncoded)` gives `None`?

---

> Q2.captcha box is shown in my html but how to validate it is correct
>   or not?

I am using scala 2.10 with play framework 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1. The reason of this is *enctype* of your form. When you use **multipart/form-data** you can access form data with:

```
request.body.asMultipartFormData
```

A2. Anyway, if I were you I would stick to the solution presented in the tutorial you mentioned and create form mapping for recaptcha values.

```
case class CaptchaForm(challenge: String, response: String)

val captchaForm = Form[CaptchaForm](
 mapping(
    "recaptcha_challenge_field" -> nonEmptyText,
    "recaptcha_response_field" -> nonEmptyText
  )(CaptchaForm.apply)(CaptchaForm.unapply)
 )
```

This way you can reuse it anywhere you need to handle Repatcha.

```
def applyForWork = Action { implicit request =>
  captchaForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => BadRequest("Captcha Param Error"),
    captchaForm => {
      println(captchaForm.challenge)
      println(captchaForm.response)
      if (check(request.remoteAddress, captchaForm.challenge, captchaForm.response)) {
        //Captcha ok
      }
    }
  ) 
}

def check(remoteAddress: String, challenge: String, response: String): Boolean = {
  val reCaptcha = new ReCaptchaImpl()
  reCaptcha.setPrivateKey(privateKey())
  val reCaptchaResponse = reCaptcha.checkAnswer(remoteAddress, challenge, response)
  reCaptchaResponse.isValid()
}
```

**Hint**

Consider using routes mapping in your template instead of hard-coded URLs. In this case replace

```
action="/applyForWork"
```

with

```
action="@routes.YourFormController.handleAction()"
```

If you ever change your mapping to an action in the routes you won't have to change all your templates that use it.

Comment: what is `mapping`?
I am getting error `not found: value mapping`

Comment: Try with import play.api.data.Forms._